# Stop rotating for a click right on the game object

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine

I have a unity game and in it, a rotating game object, which increases its speed when it is clicked.

My problem is that the game does not work as I want it to. Right now, if I click any part of the screen, it increases the game object's speed of rotation. On the other hand, if I keep my finger on the screen, the game object starts to slow down and then starts rotating in the opposite direction.

I want the rotation of the object to increase when I click on it, not just if I click on any part of the screen. Furthermore, I don't know why holding down reverses the direction of rotation.

```
var speed = 1;
var click = 0;

Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;

function Update (){

{
     transform.Rotate(0,0,speed);
}

if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{

    if(speed != 0)
    {
        speed = 0;
    } else {
        click++;
        speed = click;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use Input.*GetMouseButtonUp* or *Input.GetMouseButtonDown*, NOT A *Input.GetMouseButton*, this method used for clamping.

Try use this code:

```
var speed = 1;
var click = 0;

Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;

function Update (){

{
     transform.Rotate(0,0,speed);
}

if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{

    if(speed != 0)
    {
        speed = 0;
    } else {
        click++;
        speed = click;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here:

Firstly:

To increase speed upon clicking on the object only, use raycasting from camera, and check if it hits your object. Your object needs need a collider component on it for this to work.

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) 
{
    Transform objectHit = hit.transform;
    objectHit.Rotate(0,0,speed);
}
```

Refer to https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CameraRays.html -> Raycasting section, for more information.

Secondly:

```
Input.GetMouseButtonDown(..) // returns true at the instance your mouse button transits from up to down
Input.GetMouseButton(..) // returns true as long as your mouse button is held down
```

Use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(..)` in your `Update()` method if you want to to do something when you click on it.